# Count 'white' pixels in opencv binary image (efficiently)

Tags: c++, optimization, image-processing, opencv

I am trying to count all the white pixels in an OpenCV binary image. My current code is as follows:

```
  whitePixels = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
      if (binary.at<int>(i, j) != 0)
        ++whitePixels;
```

However, after profiling with gprof I've found that this is a very slow piece of code, and a large bottleneck in the program.

Is there a method which can compute the same value faster?

Comment: Did you try changing the height and width? I mean looping on the width and then height ? This may improve the loop, depends how the image is layed out in memory.

Comment: Can you access the image data directly instead through this at() function?

Comment: Doing as jrok suggests will probably be faster.  I wonder if [this faq entry](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/faq#How_to_access_image_pixels) is relevant.

Comment: Thanks all, I think direct data access must be the way to go. And something tells me that changing the order of the loop will be quicker too. I'll give it a go.

Comment: The at() function is VERY slow in Debug mode, although is (almost) as fast as direct pointer access in Release. It contains a CV_DbgAssert() to check bounds, which is lazy.

Comment: Great comment @vasile, I am indeed in debug mode. Good to know.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`cv::CountNonZero`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaa4b89393263bb4d604e0fe5986723914). Usually the OpenCV implementation of a task is heavily optimized.

Comment: @karlphillip you mean [`cv::countNonZero`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#cv-countnonzero)?

Comment: Perfect, an optimised, built-in function. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Added current doc link to answer (which can be updated in the future, unlike this comment).

Answer (score 0):

You can use paralell computing. You divide the image in N parts and run your code in differents threads then you get the result of each threads and after this you can add this results for obtain the finally amount.

Comment: Bill's algorithm should probably, if implemented properly, be memory-bound rather than CPU-bound.  On a normal desktop computer, usually parallelization is not helpful for memory-bound tasks.

Answer (score -2):

The last pixel in a row is usually followed by the first pixel in the next row (C code):

```
limit=width*height;
i=0;
while (i<limit)
{
  if (binary.at<int>(0,i) != 0) ++whitePixels;
  ++i;
}
```

Comment: Or implement it as a sliding pointer which will do away with the index.

Comment: And/or test two at a time at [i] and at [i+1] and add 2 to the index/pointer. This will halve the loops required.

Comment: A continuity test should be done on the matrix before with isContinuous(). If the matrix is not continuous, this method will fail.

Answer (score -2):

Actually `binary.at<int>(i, j)` is slow access!

Here is  simple code that access faster than yours.

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
{
uchar * pixel = image.ptr<uchar>(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
{
  if(pixel[j]!=0)
   {
      //do your job
   }
}
}
```